# Duplicate transaction id error in citrus payment option in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, error, payment-gateway, citrus

> HTTP Status 403 - Duplicate Transaction Id : 100000335
>
> type Status report
>
> message Duplicate Transaction Id : 100000335
>
> description Access to the specified resource (Duplicate Transaction Id
>   : 100000335) has been forbidden. Apache Tomcat/7.0.26

I got this error from Citrus after redirecting to citrus payment mode when I select this payment mode in payment methods option in Magento and clicking on "continue".

Comment: try contact citrus now only.

Comment: is it coding side issue? i have already report them.

Comment: if you use official citrus extension, i dont think it will happen.

Comment: I am using official account and its working properly on live server but it generates this error randomly in another server and also in local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, payment providers require transaction ids to be unique.

You are using the same citrus account on different systems and they generate the same order numbers which are used as transaction ids, so there are conflicts.

As a solution, you can either use a different citrus account on your test and development servers or choose a different prefix for order numbers there.

The latter can be done by changing the `prefix` column in the `eav_entity_store` database table

Comment: Thanks for answering.yes you are right i am using one citrus account for all three server. increment_prefix is present in eav_entity_store.are you talking about that?and please tell me what value i should change so that further any another problem not occur

Comment: To find the right rows, look for the `entity_type_id` in `eav_entity_type` where `entity_type_code` is "order" (usually that's the id 5). Then change `increment_prefix`  in `eav_entity_store` for every row with that `entity_type_id` (one per store)